# Sitecore Publishing Service throwing error during execution of Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.Host

Tags: publishing-service

We are trying to add a new database to SPS as a patch. We created a patch file and tried to add connection to XML using the PowerShell command `\Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.Host configuration setconnectionstring....`

While executing the PowerShell command, we are facing errors. The DB connection is correct. What could be the root cause of the below error

Sample script:

```
.\Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.Host configuration setconnectionstring Preview "server=xxx;Initial Catalog=xxx;Integrated Security=False;User ID=xxx;password=xxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
```

[image]

Comment: Which version of Sitecore and Publishing service are you using?

Comment: Can you please add the error text in your question?

Comment: Also can you try this command. `.\Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.Host.exe configuration setconnectionstring preview 'server=xxx;Initial Catalog=xxx;Integrated Security=False;User ID=xxx;password=xxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=True'`

Comment: @GowthamarajaEswaramoorthy Sitecore Verison is 10.1 and SPS Version is 6.0